# How can I sort my PHP array index?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array that I had `unset` some of its rows:

```
array (size=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'pid' => string '915' (length=3)
      'size' => string '2' (length=1)
      'count' => int 11
      'fee' => string '5500' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      'pid' => string '914' (length=3)
      'size' => string '1' (length=1)
      'count' => int 8
      'fee' => string '1500' (length=4)
  6 => 
    array (size=4)
      'pid' => string '913' (length=3)
      'size' => string '2' (length=1)
      'count' => int 5
      'fee' => string '3200' (length=4)
```

How can I sort my array index from 0 to 2?

Comment: You're not sorting, simply reindexing: `$array = array_values($array);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to reset you array keys.

See php doc for `array_values` function

[here](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$array = array_values($array);
```